# How to indicate that an Entity Framework object is implementing an interface?

Tags: vb.net, oop, entity-framework

OK, I have to begin saying that I'm working with Visual Basic. The problem is that I have a Entity Framework object and I want to indicate that this object implements a interface, for example:

```
Public Interface ICatalog
   Property created_at() As Date
   Property id() As Long
End Interface
```

Those properties are allready in the object. In c# I've done this just by declaring a partial class of the object and indicates that implements that interface, but in basic is not working, I supouse that is because of the language sintaxis used to declare that a property is implementing some property of the interface, for example:

```
Public Property created_at() As Date Implements ICatalog.created_at
```

So is there any other way to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't know too much about VB, but if I remember right, VB does not support partial classes. If you are needing to check if an object implements an interface at runtime, try casting that object to the specified interface with the equivalent of the 'as' keyword in C#. If the object is null after the cast, then you know the object doesn't implement that interface. Is this what you were trying to accomplish?

Comment: VB Does support partial classes.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this example.

```
Namespace MyAppDomain
    Public Interface IFoo
        Sub Bar()
    End Interface

    Public Interface IPerson
        Function Gender() As String
    End Interface

    Public Class MyFooPerson : Implements IFoo, IPerson
        Public Sub New()
        End Sub

        Public Sub Bar() Implements IFoo.Bar
        End Sub

        Public Function Gender() As String Implements IPerson.Gender
            Return Nothing
        End Function

    End Class
End Namespace
```

You'll notice the `MyFooPerson` Class implements the `IFoo` Interface as well as the `IPerson` Interface. Each method then implements the corresponding Interface method.

Your example doesn't say whether or not the Class containing `Public Property created_at() As Date Implements ICatalog.created_at` is Implementing the `ICatalog` Interface.

Comment: PS: I don't normally put Interfaces in with the Classes, it's just there as an example.